# Are anti-realists faced with a point where they have to take for granted the referential function of words to things that are not words?

Tags: semantics, meaning, pragmatism

Pragmatism is strongly associated with anti-realism, the view that words are meaningful not because they represent a reality independent of the word itself but because of how they are used in a given environment.

As to the question of how words have specific meaning, pragmatists typically refer to the normativity of word usage, which in turn is determined by society's use of the word. So the individual adapts a behavior that is prevalent in a society. There is some normative use of a word by other people under different conditions and the individual by some relation to these people and the conditions of word usage in the society come to use words in a like manner.

If the pragmatist is to hold on to the anti-realist view however, it seems that they must answer in what sense they distinguish between word, individual and society and how these predications are not contradictory to the anti-realism thesis that words do not represent or refer to a reality existent beyond them.

If we should understand how words come to have meaning by the environment in which they are used and the people who use them, it is difficult to see how this answer is not in some way referential to things that are taken to be existent independent of words (i.e, individuals and environments).

Comment: Existence independent of words does not have to (fundamentally) take the form of pre-existent things in a realist ontology. Reality works as a constraint on our activities, including linguistic and cognitive ones. These complex interactions are eventually sorted out into people, words, societies, intentions, feelings, etc., but that comes as a result of active cognitive work, it is co-shaped by us and reality, and does not pre-exist in a ready-made form. The environment comes to have meaning by our actions, including the use of words, not the other way around.

Comment: I don't understand your next-to-last paragraph.  can you clarify?

Comment: regarding your title question: I do not think card-carrying anti-realists do or must deny that words have a referential *function* .  on the contrary; some words (like "electron") do have such a function (play such a role); the task is to explain this role without relying on reference as an "explanatory" notion. so yes, they are faced with this problem, but no, they do not have to take reference-qua-explanation "for granted".  they try to show (as they must) how the referential functions of ordinary language can be explained pragmatically, without any prior notion of reference.

Comment: @mobileink That paragraph is pretty unclear. I meant to say that it seems that in addition to thinking of words as a category of being, the pragmatist in explaining what makes a word meaningful has to include also the categories of being individual and environment which have an existence independent of the words 'individual' and 'environment'. The two words are referencing things that exist independently of the words themselves. But this seems in contrast to most anti-realist sentiments.

Comment: @Conifold The problem as I saw it for anti-realists was accounting for how words are meaningful. Most pragmatists answer that normative use in a given environment determines word meaning. But this answer is effective only if there really is an environment and people who behave in a certain way within that environment. We might say that 'environment' is a synthesis made in part by our own behavior, but there must be some aspect of that environment which is not composed by our behavior, namely the environment that we have in mind in trying to explain what limits/determines our behavior.

Comment: @Goob: I think most pragmatists would reject the notion of "words as a category of being".  some might even reject the idea that words "exist".  And of course the anti-representationalist would reject the idea that words - whatever they are - refer in any essential sense.  it sounds like you have some presuppositions that may not hold for pragmatists.  Words need not refer in order to be useful, they just have to serve a useful function in the economy of interactions between/among us and the environment.

Comment: @mobileink I probably do have presuppositions that might not hold for every pragmatist, because I'm clumping them together with anti-realists. I never said that words need to refer to be useful. I said that words have to refer in order to be sufficient in the task of explaining how words are useful/meaningful. Your last sentence makes me convinced of this. Just what is this 'us' and this 'environment' you expect to be able to be interactive and effective in their determination of word usage if they are not some thing that is being referred to by the use of the words 'us' and 'environment'?

Comment: @Goob: "words have to refer in order to be sufficient in the task of explaining how words are useful/meaningful": just the opposite  (pragmatists are fond of overturning things).  it is the use of words that  explains how they (are deemed to) refer.  the task is to show how words can have referential uses without relying on an antecedent notion of reference. this is hard, but I believe e.g.  R. Brandom, among others, has pulled it off.  Maybe we should move this to the discussion thingie.  I don't know how, alas.

Comment: @mobileink Unfortunately I don't think I can chat yet because I'm a newb (and a goob). Guess I need a better reputation to be able to chat with others.

Comment: well on that case we can keep it up here until such time as we get kicked out!  ;)

Comment: @mobileink Minds as well. I was going to say before shenanigans ensued that I just had a thought that we might be talking over each in some way. I think I'm coming off as opposed to the pragmatist pursuit in entirety, which isn't entirely true (nice word play, yes?). I actually agree with pragmatists that a word is meaningful where it is used. But I disagree with the tendency in pragmatism to leave it at that. I'm having trouble articulating it, but if it were possible to say that words can only refer because they are used and to say that words are used mostly to refer I would say that.

Comment: have you read Brandom's "Articulating Reasons"?  by far the best brief summary of contemporary Pragmatist thought.  well worth the money.  I mostly regurgitate what I've learned from him. :)

Comment: @mobileink I have his 'Perspectives on Pragmatism' (borrowed from the library) sitting on my shelf. Admittedly only read the first few pages.

Comment: @Goob: oh, please read it asap!  that's a great book.

Comment: @mobileink Will do.

Comment: @Goob: I can honestly say that Brandom changed my (intellectual) life, which is a lot more than you can say for most philosophers.  "Reason in Philosophy" is another great one. See esp. "Why truth is not important in philosophy". plus he has an awesome beard.

Comment: @mobileink His beard is quite hypnotizing.

Comment: @Goob: I wonder if he's on the no-fly list, just because of the beard.  ok, we can stop now. ;)

Comment: @mobileink Ha, there are only so many beard jokes that can be told.